# php mysql query returns many array but need only one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$connection = db_connect();
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "
SELECT * FROM birouri 
WHERE disponibilitate = 'LIBER' 
AND locatie_actuala = 'Orhideea' 
AND pauza = '' 
AND closed_program = '' 
AND feedback = '' 
LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

            $username = $row['username'];
            $nr_birou = $row['nr_birou'];
            $disponibilitate = $row['disponibilitate'];
            $locatie_actuala = $row['locatie_actuala'];
            $pauza = $row['pauza'];
            $closed_program = $row['closed_program'];
            $feedback = $row['feedback'];
            $inregistrare_clienti = $row['inregistrare_clienti'];

            var_dump($row);
```

In database I have 6 rows that fits with my query criteria.

`var_dump($row);` returns me 1 array (first row) duplicated 7 times but I need to show only one. `Limit 1` is not working.

Help, please.

Comment: LIMIT 1 will work - **mysqli_fetch_assoc** will return an array for each row.

Comment: Unpossible!!!!!

Comment: Yea, if you are doing count you are getting a count of the number of columns.

Comment: is it in aloop?

Comment: That is the only code I have.

Comment: I pasted it exactly how i have it.

Comment: I found the issue. I was calling this function in another funtction 6 times plus the initial function. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

            $username = $row['username'];
            $nr_birou = $row['nr_birou'];
            $disponibilitate = $row['disponibilitate'];
            $locatie_actuala = $row['locatie_actuala'];
            $pauza = $row['pauza'];
            $closed_program = $row['closed_program'];
            $feedback = $row['feedback'];
            $inregistrare_clienti = $row['inregistrare_clienti'];
```

to this and it will work

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $username = $row['username'];
            $nr_birou = $row['nr_birou'];
            $disponibilitate = $row['disponibilitate'];
            $locatie_actuala = $row['locatie_actuala'];
            $pauza = $row['pauza'];
            $closed_program = $row['closed_program'];
            $feedback = $row['feedback'];
            $inregistrare_clienti = $row['inregistrare_clienti'];
}
```

there are 8 columns so your code runs 8 times but if run while loop it will only run once

Comment: assoc is  pieces of data for each columns in your case 8 , array is 1 row of data in your case